# Compiler optimization on the traveling salesman problem

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I am playing with the travelling salesman problem and am looking at the version where:
the towns are points in 2d space and there are paths from every town to all others and the lengths are the distances between the points. So it's very easy to implement the naive solution where you check all permutations of `n` points and calculate the length of the path.

I've found however that for  `n >= 10`  the compiler does some magic and prints a value that is certainly not the actual shortest path. I compile with the `Microsoft visual studio compiler in release mode with the default settings`. For values `(10,30)` it thinks for 30 seconds and then returns some number that seems like it could be correct but it is not (I check in different ways). And for  `n > 40` it calculates a result immediately and is always `2.14748e+09`.

I am looking for an explanation to what does the compiler do in the different situations (the `(10,30)` case is really interesting). And an example where these optimizations are more useful than the program just spinning to the end of the world.

```
vector<pair<int,int>> points;
void min_len()
{
    // n is a global variable with the number of points(towns)
    double min = INT_MAX;
    // there are n! permutations of n elements
    for (auto j = 0; j < factorial(n); ++j)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (auto i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        {
            sum += distance_points(points[i], points[i + 1]);
        }
        if (sum < min)
        {
            min = sum;
            s_path = points;
        }
        next_permutation(points.begin(), points.end());
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << s_path[i].first << " " << s_path[i].second << endl;
    }
    cout << min << endl;
}

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    int res = 1, i;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        res *= i;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What is your implementation of `factorial(n)`? It is probably overflowing.

Comment: And why are you using factorial anyway? You should just look at the return value from [`next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: Rather than blaming optimizations (which are not allowed to return incorrect results if the behavior is defined), you should try some debugging. For starters, track the value of `min` at the end of each iteration. Make sure  `next_permutation` does what you think it should do -- probably does, but this falls under standard things to verify when debugging. (For bonus points: notice that `2.14748e+09` is likely the value of `INT_MAX`.)

Comment: Compilers do magic. [That is their job.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)

Comment: @JaMiT I know it depends, but how long should I expect to w8 for 30! permutations?

Comment: If a billion permutations can be handled in a second, then 30! permutations should take somewhat over 8 trillion millennia. You might want to grab a snack while you **wait**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your factorial function is overflowing. Try replacing it with one returning `int64_t` and see your code taking 3 years to terminate for n > 20.

```
constexpr uint64_t factorial(unsigned int n) {
  return n ? n * factorial(n-1) : 1;
}
```

Also, you don't need to calculate this at all. The `std::next_permutation` function returns 0 when all permutations have occured (starting from sorted position).